224.0.0.0/4 In IPv4 Routing Table
Has anyone seen this before, I noticed some weirdness and ran a netstat -r and found this atypical IP address I have never seen before:
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      192.168.1.75    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       172.24.16.1   5256

I found this article seems to explain the route I'm seeing fairly well:
Use ip route add to add multicast routes to multiple interfaces

Pretty much anyone should be seeing that. Those are the entries for multicast, one for each local interface.
